# select choice from django model

Tags: django, angularjs

Can i write `ng-repeat` to iterate through the choices in a Django model field and display them? How can i do it? Should I make a separate API for this or what?

```
APPROVAL_CHOICES = (
        (u'Good condition', u'Good condition'),
        (u'Bad condition', u'Bad condition'),
        (u'Broken', u'Broken'),
    )
status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=APPROVAL_CHOICES)
```

I have something like the following, but it's not working:

```
<label>Statuss</label>
    <select>
         <option value="" selected>--Please select Inventory statuss--</option> 
         <option value="inventory.status[0]" >Good Condition</option>   
         <option value="inventory.status[1]" >Bad Condition</option>    
         <option value="inventory.status[2]" >Broken</option>   
    </select><br/>
```

And here is my API:

```
    objects: [
    {
        category: {},
        count: 1,
        created: "2014-02-24T16:07:12.903555",
        description: "Car description for image",
        id: 1,
        location: "IT nodala",
        name: "Baterija AA",
        resource_uri: "/api/v1/inventory/1",
        slug: "baterija-aa",
        status: "Good condition"
    },
```

Comment: Eh.. what is not working exactly? Did you try get_<field>_display() method already for displaying chosen fields human-readable text value?

Comment: I cant display the choices in fronted using angularjs. Haven't tried that, can u give any example ?

Comment: Imagine -i know nothing about angular.js but i know some about django.  What are you trying to do in the sense of django? IF you want to print out display value of some field then use get_foo_display method. IF you want to skip django forms for rendering and just push serialized form fields and options from django to html, then you would have to write something to replace form fields rendering with serializing.

Answer (score 0):

using ng repeat like this

```
'<select data-ng-model="selectedField">' +
      ' <option data-ng-repeat="v in choices" value="v">v</option>' +
'</select> ' ;
```

Comment: it shows the values, but it doesn't select the current value after submitting the form. Any tips?

Comment: check the ngModel on select... if "v in choice" your "v" is an object and not a text field then you might need something like: ' <option data-ng-repeat="object in choices" value="object.valuefield">object.textfield</option>'

Comment: not it isnt even displaying anything, i dont know what happened but i have this `<select data-ng-model="selectedField">
   <option data-ng-repeat="v in choices" value="v">v</option> 
 </select>` But nothing is showing up

Comment: what the name of ur variable on $scope?? is it choices?? i had given it just for example....

Comment: i have `$scope.info = data;` to get data from api that what you wanted ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question is about how to use [select](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) tag with angular js you can use the [ngOption directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).
From the [AngularJS docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select):

> ## ngOptions
>
> The ngOptions attribute can be used to dynamically generate a list of  elements for   the  element using the array or object obtained by evaluating the ngOptions   comprehension_expression.
>
> When an item in the  menu is selected, the array element or object property   represented by the selected option will be bound to the model identified by the ngModel   directive.
>
> ...Note: ngOptions provides an iterator facility for the  element which should be used instead of ngRepeat when you want the select model to be bound to a non-string value. This is because an option element can only be bound to string values at present.

with this [jsfiddles](http://jsfiddle.net/qWzTb/):

```
<body ng-app="demoApp">
  <div ng-controller="DemoController">
    <div>
      <h2>Incorrect</h2>
      <p>
        We might expect the select box to be initialized to "two,"
        but it isn't because these are two different objects.
      </p>
      <select
        ng-model="incorrectlySelected"
        ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options"
      >
      </select>
      The value selected is {{ incorrectlySelected.value }}.
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Correct</h2>
      <p>
        Here we are referencing the same object in <code>$scope.correctlySelected</code>
        as in <code>$scope.options</code>, so the select box is initialized correctly.
      </p>
      <select
        ng-model="correctlySelected"
        ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options"
      >
      </select>
      The value selected is {{ correctlySelected.value }}.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Check the [docs form more exmaples](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).